# Duplicate entry error when integrating appodeal

Tags: android, android-multidex

error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager$SavedState$1.class

Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':cheetah-mobile-3.4.7')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0') {
        force = true;
    }
    compile('com.android.support:design:24.0.0') {
        force = true;
    }

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.deano2390:MaterialShowcaseView:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked your libs folder?

If it contains recycle view , remove it and add to `build.gradle` so

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'.
```